# How iPhone games/apps can connect to other iphones

Tags: iphone

I wonder how iphone games and apps can connect to other devices with the same app/game. Like games, where you create an account and can play with your friend. Does anyone know a site where it's briefly explained or can anyone just explain in some sentences what the "steps" are. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For games specifically, look into apple's gamecenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the tutorials under Network programming [at Ray Wenderlich's site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials). They are nicely done and should help you grasp the main concepts.

Answer (score 1):

If you had bothered to try you would have found the very first tab "Technologies" on the very first page of Apple's developer site would take you to this page on Networking where the very first item is about GameCenter.

https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/networking.html